# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) Pointers, strings and arrays

Tags: arrays, c, linux, pointers, c-strings

I have these three files main.h, 4-main.c and 4-print_rev.c and all three are required to print a string in reverse.
I am not permitted to use standard libs, hence the reason for not using strlen() or printf() and I have to use _putchar() which performs same actions of putchar()

However, when I compile and run on my Linux sandbox, I get segmentation fault (core dumped) error.
I used an online compiler and it worked just as it should. Please help.[image]

main.h

```
#define MAIN_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _putchar(char c);
void reset_to_98(int *n);
void swap_int( int *a, int *b);
int _strlen(char *s);
void _puts(char *s);
void print_rev(char *s);

#endif
```

4-main.c

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * main - check the code
 *
 * Return: Always 0.
 */
int main(void)
{
    char *str;

    str = "I do not fear computers. I fear the lack of them - Isaac Asimov";
    print_rev(str);
    return (0);
}
```

4-print_rev.c

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * print_rev - prints a string
 * @s: the string to be printed
 */

void print_rev(char *s)
{
        int i;

        while (s[i] != '\0')
        {
                i++;
        }
        while (i > 0)
        {
                _putchar(s[i-1]);
                i--;
        }
        _putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: The variable i in print_rev is not initialized int i;. It seems you mean int i = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I realized that not initializing my iterator i to 0 was the cause of the segmentation fault.

So I updated my 4-print_rev.c to this and I am good to go.
Thanks again @Vlad

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * print_rev - prints a string
 * @s: the string to be printed
 */

void print_rev(char *s)
{
        int i = 0;

        while (s[i] != '\0')
        {
                i++;
        }
        while (i > 0)
        {
                _putchar(s[i-1]);
                i--;
        }
        _putchar('\n');
}
```